# Windows 7 Home hangs at "Welcome" screen

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, boot

UPDATE 3: I'm currently assisting him in getting a spare hard drive ready to migrate data over to a new Windows 7 installation.  On top of that I'm having him run Windows Memory Diagnostic, then will have him run a few passes of memtest86+ to see if anything is wrong memory-wise.  The freezing seems to be happening at extremely random times.  I'm also going to run a Malware/virus check on his computer, but since he hardly downloads programs and generally practices safe browsing habits I doubt it's that.  I may run Prime95 and some sort of GPU Benchmark test to make sure it's not the CPU/GPU either.

UPDATE 2.1: Ran CrystalDiskInfo for SMART data info.  C5 Current Sector Pending Count is 84.  C6 Uncorrectable sector count is 83.  Should I be worried?

UPDATE 2: It looks like his profile got corrupted, so I made a new profile and copied over the settings.  It seemed OK for a little while.  However, a few hours later, his explorer.exe ended up freezing AGAIN after he tried accessing the System Properties window.  Then he got this error:

"The instruction at 0x776F5319 referenced memory at 0x71CE84E4.the required data was not placed into memory because of an I/O error status of 0xc000000e.
Click on ok to terminate the program."

Then the computer reset itself - it froze at the FOXCONN logo - after another restart the computer booted up again fine.

Something tells me the hard drive is going bad.  What do you all think?

UPDATE: chkdsk /R allowed him to boot back to the Windows 7 desktop, but his desktop profile got completely reset.  I'm trying to remote into his machine now to see if he's logged on as a temporary profile so I'll post an update soon.

**ORIGINAL QUESTION BELOW**

I'm asking on behalf of a friend who's currently having problems with his machine.  Windows 7 Home 32-bit.  He's too far away for me to help by going over to his house - I'm helping him over the Internet.

This is his current machine: http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16883227134

The only two changes he made to that machine is to swap out the gfx card for a EVGA GTX 460 and the PSU for a Corsair TX650.

Here's what happened:
He was playing a computer game (fairly CPU/GPU intensive) and had some music going in the background in foobar while playing.  Suddenly, he notices the music stopped playing, so he switches to foobar to try to close it, but it freezes up (window won't respond).  So he figures it's just foobar having a bad day and force quits that program.  Suddenly, his game won't respond, so he force quits that, then the entire computer just went to crap at that point, so he hits the restart button on his machine.

Computer POSTS fine, but now he gets stuck at the Windows "welcome" screen (his account is set to auto-login).  HD activity light is solid yellow but he doesn't hear HDD activity.  He tried booting into Safe Mode - gets stuck at the "welcome screen".  Tried a STartup Repair within Windows 7, it found a few problems, but still gets stuck at welcome.  I advised him to boot off the DVD - sfc /scannow found nothing (couldn't use the regular /scannow option; says there's a repair pending, had to use use offbootdir/offwindir command switches).  Ran startup repair 3 times - found nothing.

My friend runs virus/malware scans on a regular basis, so he's fairly sure it's not that either.

Right now I'm having my friend run chkdsk /R on the computer while in this Startup Recovery mode - so far it's caught a few bad sectors.

However at this point I'm kinda wondering which way to go if chkdsk doesn't fix it.  Quick Google search said someone had success by booting Windows with bootlogging on - some others have success with running the aforemented chkdsk, etc.  The fact that Windows cannot even boot into Safe Mode concerns me.

While we're waiting for chkdsk /R to finish, are there any other options I can give my friend short of reinstalling Windows 7?  He has his data on a separate partition so that's not a major problem (though it'll be an annoyance for him).  I suspect his hard drive may be having some issues, but my main concern is getting him back up and running before we start diagnosing the hard drive (I may have him run some sort of SMART test utility later).

Comment: "The fact that Windows cannot even boot into Safe Mode concerns me." Safe mode is not an option to boot into or the same problem happens after you try safe mode?

Comment: As I said earlier in my post, the latter, it hangs on Safe Mode boot at the same place, the Welcome screen.

Comment: Isnt there some "repair" features that can occur at a boot up, that happen behind the scenes? I have heard it only rarely reported hidden chkdsk?. Take this scenario, he crashed hard, writes were probably occuring somewhere, they reboot, and there is a high level of disk activity, that is NOT allowed to complete proper (or will not complete for some reason) , they bail out of that activity and have disk corruption.   Main problem actually the crash on heavy use. Second problem, something was again writing to the disk. weather that would have completed or not, or if there is say AVsoftware?

Comment: The kind of AV software that likes to run very very early, and can conflict with other activity (that being good when the intention is to spot everything even back at the beginning)   Or retract some of that, the creation of the temp user itself, is the high level of activity.

Comment: More interesting stuff on the HD light on, but the user no longer hearing the head moving.  http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/w7itprogeneral/thread/a3cd974b-4758-44bb-b1c0-289ef813b2e6/  A chkdsk using all the memory of the system. The intent being (sort-of) that a "repair" should be able to takeover and use the whole machine , so it can get done, and normal activity can ensue.  It also figures that this would be "testing" :-)  all the physical memory in the system, heating it up good, and any tiny ram flaws would show (most of which can be adjusted for).

Comment: Update 2, yes, disk. but dont discount motherboard ram, do the memtest86, and make sure that the ram is all ok first.  as it can effect the data going to the drive (not the internal problems of the drive)

Comment: @Psycogeek Made one more update about the SMART on the disk.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S.M.A.R.T. Smart data is interpreted pretty badly by users, assisted by programs that are (as much as) wrongly interpreting the data. Add to that the manufactures have different thresholds or allowances for various occurances.  The "raw" data might be interpreted some, and then you must Understand how the other info is used, until it goes beyond the "threshold" the quantity(s) are sort of business as usual :-)  It even takes me 30 minutes to analise my own for a fact.  I dont care unless the quantity is growing. or manufactures tool confirms , to many other things.

Comment: a quick example http://www.wilderssecurity.com/showthread.php?t=318288  there is a high raw value there, and the middle one, looks ok right?  Then why is it Burning up :-)  see the temps?  assuming that is correct temps, they missed something that might be more important?

Comment: Ohoh, and if I can manage to interpret it correct, the threshold is 0?  and they are still a long way from it getting to 0.

Comment: @Psycogeek You have a point.  The manufacturer threshold on the drive is 100.  My friend is still getting random freezes though, freezes that never happened before.  I'm having him do a Spyware scan to see if it could be something simple like that, but I'm also having him run memory tests via Windows Memory Diagnostic and Memtest86+.  There's no rhyme or reason to the freezing so far (he's had it freeze while trying to open up the System Properties menu or use Firefox).

Comment: I would also want to do the cpu and gpu tests Prime and furmark and/or OCCT for example. to get "hardware" out of the way. then sfc scan because some data might have been lost. There is also a spare registry backup made by the system. It might be restored to get back some? (depends), Then checking for running software.

Comment: @Psycogeek sfc /scannow was the first thing I did while troubleshooting - it didn't find anything so that's good.  Data hasn't been lost - I was able to migrate his profile and settings to a new one.  I'm going to do the memory tests first, then try the Prime/Furmark tests later - since its happening randomly outside of graphics intensive programs/games, I think it's probably the memory or hard drive.

Comment: the original problem(s) of a hard crash, could be a hard drive (HD not responding system eventually clogs and freezes), but also is similar for not enough cooling of many things, including items that have no temp sensors (voltage regulation and ram). and overclock issues.

Comment: @Psycogeek He doesn't overclock anything.  Everything is stock speeds.  I'll have him check his computer temps when he runs Prime95 with CoreTemp.  His GPU does go to about 70-80C on full load, but so does mine and it doesn't crash.  I'm going to have him run a memtest overnight.

Comment: For readability, you might want to add a heading to the original question. It took me a moment to find that after the updates.

Comment: @Steve Done.  Good idea.  It was quite an adventure, to say the least.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just closing up this topic since I've swapped out the hard drive.  No more problems since.  I wish I could give points to the contributors of this discussion, as I learned myself quite a lot on what to do if this ever happens to my own machine.

Special thanks to @Psycogeek for his assistance!